# Understanding some Python code

Tags: python

I'm working my way through Gmail access using imaplib and came across:

```
# Count the unread emails
status, response = imap_server.status('INBOX', "(UNSEEN)")
unreadcount = int(response[0].split()[2].strip(').,]'))
print unreadcount
```

I just wish to know what:

```
status,
```

does in front of the "response =". I would google it, but I have no idea what I'd even ask to find an answer for that :(.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a function returns a tuple, it can be read by more than one variable.

```
def ret_tup():
    return 1,2 # can also be written with parens

a,b = ret_tup()
```

a and b are now 1 and 2 respectively

Answer (score 5):

See this page:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Section 5.3 mentions 'multiple assignment' aka 'sequence unpacking'

Basically, the function imap_server returns a tuple, and python allows a shortcut that allows you to initialize variables for each member of the tuple. You could have just as easily done

```
tuple = imap_server.status('INBOX', "(UNSEEN)")
status = tuple[0]
response = tuple[1]
```

So in the end, just a syntactic shortcut. You can do this with any sequence-like object on the right side of an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Though the answers given are certainly sufficient, an quick application of this python feature is the ease of swapping values.

In a normal language, to exchange the values of variables `x` and `y`, you would need a temporary variable

```
z = x
x = y
y = z
```

but in python, we can instead shorten this to

```
x, y = y, x
```